# Invisible network within a LAN

Tags: networking, server, lan

I and another student at our school are involved with a project, given to us by the network administrator of said school. The project is to link three computers together, along with a server (the computers are running windows 7, and the server's running ubuntu server 14.10) and make the whole thing invisible to the administration at the board office. Why? I'm not sure, I accepted because I thought it would be fun. But now I'm stuck, we have the server running fine, but all devices can be seen. I was told to use OpenVPN and connect trough a hub, but I'm not sure hot that would work. For making the computer invisible, I have no idea.

TL;DR
I need help setting up a phantom network with up to 4 computers connected to it.

Thanks in advance!

```
   kulalolk
```

Comment: use separate VLAN. Ask your network admin to create a different VLAN.